# Swift - How can I make a text field match the keyboard during animation, when I have a bottom tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard

I have an app which has a tab bar at the bottom of the screen (40 pt high), and a UITextField directly above that. When the keyboard becomes active, I want to animate the text field so that it moves up while sticking to the top of the keyboard.

However, this is very tricky because the text field should not move until the keyboard animation gets past the bottom tab bar.

So here's the animation I want to achieve:

- Keyboard begins to animate upwards, text field stays still
- Keyboard reaches the top of the bottom tab bar
- Text field starts to animate upwards, and matches the rest of the keyboard animation curve, so that the bottom of the text field is locked to the top of the keyboard.

I would like to use a custom easing function for this, because it doesn't look right if I just add a small delay to the animation. It compresses the animation curve, which means that the text field does not stay locked to the top of keyboard.

I've tried a few parametric animation libraries, but am having difficulty getting them to work with Swift.

I've found many resources for cases where the text field is at the very bottom of the screen, such as [this post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/08/animate-around-ios-keyboard/). But unfortunately, they can't easily be tweaked to account for a bottom tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve effect like in messages app in ios you can do it like this:

First don't put textfield directly into view hierarchy.

Override `canBecomeFirstResponder` method in viewController and return `true` from it.

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then override `inputAccessoryView` method in view controller and return the view that you want to show on top of the keyboard.

```
override func inputAccessoryView() -> UIView {
    return textField
}
```

Note: You have to create textField and set it frame. You can create it as lazy property of view controller